# matplotlib crashes when making many plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a loop to make ~90 plots (png's) with matplotlib (jupyter notebook). When looping through each plot, at around plot 37, python crashes (kernel dies). At first I thought it was because I was not clearing the figure correctly, but that does not seem to be the issue... Here is an abridged version of my code:

```
%pylab inline
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy import stats
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
from scipy.signal import savgol_filter
from joblib import Parallel, delayed
import gc


for p in plots_agm:
    cnt=cnt+1
    print(cnt)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(8.5,11),sharex=True,sharey=True)
    ax = ax.flatten()
    for i,d in enumerate(dat.keys()):


   ######### A BUNCH OF CALCULATIONS AND PLOTTING FOR EACH FIGURE ###########

    fig.savefig('+p.replace(' ','_')+'_v3.png')
    #pp.savefig(fig)
    plt.clf()
    plt.close(fig)
    #plt.cla()
    #plt.close()
    #plt.clf()
    #plt.cla()
    #fig.clf()
    #pylab.close(fig)
    #plt.close(fig)
    #plt.close('all')
    #del(fig)
    #del(ax)
    gc.collect()
```

I have tried a bunch of ways to clear the figure (as you can see in the commented out parts of my code).

In the terminal where the jupyter notebook is running, all it says is:

WARNING:root:kernel 9a4a2b77-0b43-4700-a30f-2c7743463c30 restarted

Comment: You probably already checked but do you have any growing arrays/matrices in your for loop? If so, you could use `del` to delete and save memory.

Comment: Yes - already tried this as well. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: First thing you need to find out is if the problem is related to the number of plots alone. Therefore I would suggest to plot 100 minimal example plots and save those as png.

Comment: Following ImportanceOfBeingErnest advice, I did not have any issues... Therefore, I examined my code more and found duplicates in one of my arrays which must have been crashing the kernel... now my code is working... Thanks qbzenker and ImportanceOfBeingErnest for the advice!